# Why local gradient of output node and hidden node are different?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I got a question studying Machine Learning.

The author says that
[image]

in this diagram, the local gradient of output node is defined by:

[image]

and in below diagram,
[image]

the local graident of hidden node is defined by:

[image]

epsilon is defined like this:

[image]

By chaing rule, those two equations have same structure, except -.
I know that there are many nodes between hidden node and output, but that doesn't explain why there's -.

can anyone help me why those are different??